# how to resize images in itextsharp table

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms

I'm trying to print out a receipt from a database using a webform. I wanted to include a logo which is on the left side of the first table. the logo(logo.gif) could not be resize and it spread within the cell. I tried changing the size of the image using absolutescale and scalepercent, but the image still fill the cell. Is there a way to manipulate the image so that it could be smaller?

these are my codes

```
    protected void btn_con_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PdfPTable pdfTbl = new PdfPTable(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
        foreach (TableCell headcell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            PdfPCell pdcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headcell.Text));
            pdfTbl.AddCell(pdcell);
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            foreach (TableCell tblcell in gvrow.Cells)
            {
                PdfPCell pdcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblcell.Text));
                pdfTbl.AddCell(pdcell);
            }
        }



        Document pfddoc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pfddoc, Response.OutputStream);


        pfddoc.Open();


        string imageURL = Server.MapPath(".") + "/logo.gif";

        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageURL);


        //Resize image depend upon your need

        jpg.ScaleToFit(50f, 50f);

        //Give space before image

        jpg.SpacingBefore = 5f;

        //Give some space after the image

        jpg.SpacingAfter = 0f;

        jpg.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;


        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("\b Putri Sejinjang Spa \b \n Rumah Kedai Mara, Lot 12953, \n Jalan Tun Datuk Patinggi Haji Abdul Rahman Yakub \n Taman Heritage, Sarawak,93050 Kuching, Sarawak \n " +
            "Tel: 082-428 660, Fax: 082-417660, Whatsapp: 013-8448616 \n website:PutriSejinjangSpa.com.my, e-mail: putri_sejinjang07@yahoo.com.my \n\n", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12));
        para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;


        //start
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.TotalWidth = 50f;

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invois Putri Sejinjang Spa"));
        table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        cell.Colspan = 2;

        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell.Colspan = 2;
        table.AddCell(jpg);
        jpg.ScalePercent(24f);

        //jpg.ScaleAbsolute(10f, 10f);
        table.AddCell(para);



        pfddoc.Add(table);
        //end
        pfddoc.Add(pdfTbl);


        pfddoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Resit.pdf");
        Response.Write(pfddoc);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

set the images height and width on the server side exactly the same with ScaleToFit the images sizes.

jpg.ScaleAbsolute(40f, 40f);

jpg.ScaleToFit(120f, 155.25f);

Comment: doesn't seem to change anything. Do I have to change the perimeter of the table in order to change the image size?